# IntelijIDEA (Goland) uses /private/var/folders/

Tags: macos, go, webstorm, goland

My Goland's runner (run/debug configurations) uses /private/var/folders/7b/50mzg8x17q55rxfg3b0kpj88xcm2lx/T in `os.Args[0]`. I know that `os.Args[0]` is the path to my program, but can I do `os.Args[0]` to be my working directory in Goland runner?

P.S. Working directory in Edit configurations set properly

Answer (score 2):

> I know that os.Args[0] is the path to my program, but can I do os.Args[0] to be my working directory in Goland runner?

No, you cannot make `os.Args[0]` to be the working directory, since as you correctly identified, it's used to locate your program on disk.

There are two changes you can make:

- change your code to stop relying on `os.Args[0]` and start using `os.Getwd()` to get the working directory. Then you can edit your `Run Configuration` via `Run | Edit Configurations... | <name of the run configuration> | Working Directory` parameter.
- if you really want you binary to be in a certain directory, then you can go to `Run | Edit Configurations... | <name of the run configuration> | Output directory` to have the IDE run the compiler and place the executable wherever you need to.

If you need to make these changes for all future Run Configurations, then edit `Run | Edit Configurations... | Templates | Go Build`, or `Go Test` and change either the `Working Directory` or the `Output Directory` fields. Existing `Run Configurations` will not be changed.